# error: repository [dockerimage] not found: does not exist or no pull access-docker

Tags: docker

Issue:

I am trying to maven build a proprietary application and the build fails with the following output:

repository [privatedockerimage] not found: does not exist or no pull access.

I am able to pull the dockerimage from our private docker repository. But when I tried to build the application, the application fails to build

checks

1. Docker daemon was running.
2. logged into my dockerhub account from command line. ( to pull the private docker image )

Expected Behavior

Build pass

Actual Behavior

> repository [privatedockerimage] not found: does not exist or no pull
>   access.

Could you suggest what could be the possible issues. Unfortunately both the application and dockerimage are private and I can't provide exact steps to reproduce.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have a free account on docker hub, you could store several private containers, but you must make your repo as public to be able to pull it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have only permission to pull the image.You don't have permission to build it since it is private repository.Please check what is your access level with your account.